Chain rubs front derailleur cage even after adjusting
I have a generic hybrid bike with a 3x9 Shimano group set. The rear shifts fine but the front has major shifting issues. After adjusting the height, rotational alignment and L-limit screw I still have problems with the chain rubbing against the innermost part of the derailleur cage and not shifting down from the middle chainring to the smallest.
With the shift cable disconnected, L-limit screw turned all the way out and the chain on the largest rear sprocket I still get rubbing as seen in the picture. The front derailleur even hits the frame so it can’t go any further inward. What are my options for solving this? The crank set is Shimano FC-M371, the front derailleur FD-M531 and the bottom bracket BB-UN300.


I was going to suspect a problem with the chainrings or missing bottom bracket spacers, but since you have a square taper bottom bracket and a crankset with riveted chainrings it can’t be either.

I found the issue here. I had recently bought a new bottom bracket but it turns out that the spindle length I bought was too short for the crank. So it was too far inboard and thus making the chain run and the preventing the derailleur from shifting down.
